# Can I get to an index of parsed XML using XStream

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xstream

I am using XStream library for XML parsing. I was wondering if the library allows jumping to a particular node directly using the index.

So for e.g.

```
<details>
  <personal>
      <basicInfo>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <phoneNumber>9999999999</phoneNumber>
        <dateOfBirth>1990-01-01</dateOfBirth>
      </basicInfo>
      <address>
        <street>random St.</street>
        <city>City</city>
        <stateProv>BC</stateProv>
        <country>CA</country>
        <postCode>12345</postCode>
      </address>
    </personal>
  <personal>
      <basicInfo>
        <firstName>John2</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe2</lastName>
        <phoneNumber>9999999999</phoneNumber>
        <dateOfBirth>1990-01-01</dateOfBirth>
      </basicInfo>
      <address>
        <street>random St.2</street>
        <city>City2</city>
        <stateProv>BC2</stateProv>
        <country>CA2</country>
        <postCode>12345</postCode>
      </address>
    </personal>
</details>
```

For the XML above I would like to skip the first `<personal>...</personal>`
and only process the second node. Can I call it using an index.

Answer (score 0):

XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again.

I am not sure what you mean by process in this context, but if your POJO for serialization is set up correctly to contain a List of "personal" nodes. I don't see why you couldn't deserialize the XML and remove the unwanted node after the fact.

Comment: In the above XML as you can see I have two nodes called as <personal>
Is there someway that I can specify an index and get a hold of the second one directly. I do not want to process the first one. In actual scenario I do not want to process hundreds of records like and select some nodes only on a particular index i.e. record number 9 or record number 228 etc. Like that. I would not like the library to hold all the records in the memory.

Comment: Then, XStream is not the library you want. Try looking into XPath. Perhaps, you could isolate a particular node using XPath and then deserialize that section with XStream.

Comment: But XPath only works with DOM parser. It will hog the whole memory as it loads the whole file before it can allow index based node fetching.

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, then use whatever XML parser you configured XStream with. XStream is a serialization/deserialization library.

Comment: I am using StaxParser. It gives me an advantage of Speed but does not give me the flexibility of index based node fetching. But based on what I've read it is possible. I guess I'll use some custom approach.. Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, vtd-xml is the only XML parsing routine that natively offers indexing feature, called vtd+XML.